# Create Node.js / Express Websocket with WS on shared server with unique path

Tags: node.js, express, ws

I'm trying to set up a Websocket server on Node.js / Express with WS ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#simple-server)) on a shared server with a unique path:

```
import express from 'express'
const app = express()

const wss = new WebSocketServer({ noServer: true, path: '/websocket' });
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('Client connected');
});

const port = process.env.PORT

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Serving on port ${port}`);
});
```

React client code:

```
let socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/websocket');

socket.onopen = () => {
  console.log('socket open')
};
```

I cannot get them to connect and just can't figure out what's wrong. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Why do you say that `I cannot get them to connect`?

Comment: My client websocket connection fails to connect to the server

Comment: I think you need to follow a simple example about ws and express, and see how it works. There is a lot of "issue" in your snippet code.